# column pinning in excel export ag-grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid-react

Hi I can able to do column pinning in UI side using ag-grid. Is there is any option to carry the same **column pinning property even in export to excel in ag-grid**.
Also please suggest is there any way to carry the pinned columns in all pages of print preview through coding apart from excel.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could contextualize your question with snippets of code with examples of what did you tried so far.